# Following a ../ link on my live site behaves differently then when developing it with vscode and Chrome

Tags: html, web, directory, hyperlink, subdirectory

While debugging my site, I have noticed a weird thing happening. Lets say the html file has a hyperlink like so:

```html
<a href="../">This hyperlink uses "../" to take you back one directory</a>
```

If I debug my own site in vscode and use chrome, if I click this, it gives me a weird page that says "Index of /Users/myusername/code/public_html/aboutme/" and shows all of the files in that directory. But then when I upload the files to my host, everything works just fine. Why is this? I suspect it may have to do with the way that "index.html" works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **typical** configuration for an HTTP server which is serving static files (i.e. mapping URLs directly onto files on the filesystem) is that if the URL maps onto a directory then to look for a file named *index.html* (or similar) and response with that.

For example, when using Apache HTTPD, this is handled by the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

When dealing with a `file:///` scheme URL then there is no HTTP server which can do that mapping and the code internal to browsers which handles `file:///` scheme URLs doesn't do it either.